# New Line on Javascript Summary / Documentation

Tags: javascript, documentation, summary

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 & Resharper 10 for my javascript project. I'm writing documentation for my javascript functions. These documentation also helps me with intellisense when I'm writing code.

```
    /**
     * @description Get element(s) by a query. 
     * An ex: 
     * find all paragraphs with the class "summary" in the article with ID "first"
     * "article#first p.summary"
     * @param {String} query
    */
    getByQuery: function(query) {
        return exampleFunction(query);
    }
```

But I can't find a way for creating new lines in javascript summary/documentation.

Please look at this picture, you will understand what I mean;
[image]

I tried;

```
<br>
<br/>
@newline
\n
<para>
</para>
@example
```

Comment: Only add a new empty line if you want separate line in comment.

Answer (score -1):

try using < br > for your new line.

```html
My line one<br>
My line two
```

**edit:**

Sorry the < br > is for eclipse documentation.
For Visual Studio try < para >

```html
<para>My line one</para>
<para>My line two</para>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. But it didn't work. Now text comes like; "Get element(s) by a query. An ex: <br> find all..."

Comment: I just updated my answer, in Visual Studio you need to use <para /> to have a new line. The answer <br> is used in Eclipse

Comment: Sorry, second example is not working too.

Comment: Yep sorry , edited again

Comment: Hello, thanks for help but it's not working. I think your solution is valid but not in my case. Because I'm using JsDoc comment standarts, not xml-comment standarts.

Comment: Ok I understand, did you tried this  ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/29284639/2518101

Comment: I checked, not working on this ide I think ( Visual Studio ). I also check my resharper configuration and visual studio's options. Everything seems ok. But no luck for solution.